# Запрос SQLite на удаление дублей но с 1 условием

Tags: sql, sqlite

Профи прошу у вас совета.
Есть задача надо удалит дубли с бд sqlite (может быть SQL подойдет)
но с  1 условием   таблица такая:

```
id  | title     | published            | 
0   | comment 1 | 2017-05-12T18:37:31  | 
1   | comment 2 | 2017-05-13T19:37:31  |
2   | comment 1 | 2017-05-16T12:43:07  |
3   | comment 2 | 2017-05-05T13:46:16Z |
4   | comment 3 | 2017-05-05T16:46:16Z |
5   | comment 1 | 2017-05-05T17:46:16Z |
6   | comment 1 | 2017-05-05T20:46:16Z |
```

И так задача надо удалить дубли строк, основываясь на колонке **title** и **published**
Но по одной  уникальной записи каждой строки оставить, что бы по дате она была более поздняя.
**Примечание:** Не знаю с чем связанно но в базе имеется 2 вида записи даты

```
2017-05-16T14:43:07  
2017-05-05T15:46:16Z
```

Думаю это тоже надо учесть.

Итоговый вариант должен быть таким

```
id  | title     | published            | 
0   | comment 1 | 2017-05-12T18:37:31  | 
1   | comment 2 | 2017-05-13T19:37:31  |
2   | comment 3 | 2017-05-16T12:43:07  |
```

Предложите два вариант **SELECT И DELETE** что бы сначала проверил как правильно ли выборка выполняется.

Вот скрин что бы примерно представлять.
P.S. тут еще кучу других полей есть я не знаю нужно ли они для составления запроса если да, то я предоставлю их

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем определяется уникальность, полем title или title и published?

Comment: Как раз таки там нету уникальности, есть много повторяющихся строк, и надо найти какой-то запрос который смог бы удалить дублирующие строки. есть **поле  feedID**, оно имеет целое число я так понял этот как родитель

Comment: Все равно не понял, что вы подразумеваете под уникальностью строк, что будет в вашем случае в group by?

Comment: извините в голове у меня одна абстракция по этой теме,  и не получается перевести в саму суть. 
**Пример:**  Из 10  дублирующих строк,  оставить 1-2  с более поздней датой. Какие-то нужно делать сравнение  с другими может быть полями. Как я ранее говорил что тут их много я просто не все выложил

Comment: Основная задача не просто очистить базу от дублей а оставить по 1 записи каждого дублированного сходства. Не питайте меня за такое изложение мыслей )))

Comment: Оставить последнюю запись не проблема, главно знать,что такое дубль, судя по тестовой таблице, под дублями вы подразумеваете строки с одинаковым значением в столбце title

Comment: @PrimusSingularis именно так

Comment: Это называется не "удалить дубли", а "выбрать первую/последнюю запись в группе". Выборка реализуется вульгарным `SELECT title, MAX(published) FROM table GROUP BY title`. Удаление - использованием этой выборки как критерия отбора. А поле id в показанном итоговом состоянии таблицы вообще ни в какие ворота не лезет - с какого перепугу `id=2` стало `title='comment 3'`, если раньше было `comment 1`?

Comment: данная таблица это только пример, `дату id и title` я просто придумал 
вместо `comment 3` может быть любое название. Сейчас проверил ваш код  он выбрал только  1) 1415 строк а в базе свыше 6700 2) выборка взяла не дубли

Comment: где-то писали что надо использовать count(*) для подсчета  строк которые одинаковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так можно найти дубликаты для удаления:

```
select * from news s 
  where exists (select 1 from (
         select title, max(published) as published 
            from news 
            group by title having count(*) > 1) dn 
      where s.title = dn.title and s.published < dn.published);
```

Так удалить:

```
delete from news
  where exists (select 1 from (
         select title, max(published) as published 
            from news 
            group by title having count(*) > 1) dn 
      where title = dn.title and published < dn.published);
```

На работоспособность не проверял.
И запрос не удалит строки у которых published тоже дублируется, проверьте наличие таких строк запросом:

```
select title, published from news group by title, published having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: а что такое `dn`? и `news s`

Comment: код который должен удалить вот выдал лог 
`(заняло 10мс, 0 строк изменено)`    
То есть ничего не удалилось
Может быть задействовать в запросе поле **feedId**  там целое идет число и является как группа.

Comment: dn и s просто alias'ы что бы различать контексты. А select нормально отработал? С датами ещё разобраться надо

Comment: SELECT выборку делает но в ней все равно есть дубли.
вот http://prntscr.com/fc3a2t

Comment: и вот  http://prntscr.com/fc3cx7

Comment: В select должно быть то, что надо удалить, так что дубли могут быть. Можно переписать delete разными способами, например использовать where id in (), а в скобках select из ответа, только * заменить на id: delete from news where id in (select id from news s ...)

Comment: пожалуйста,  а можно полный код я sql вообще не знаю на таком уровне как вы

Comment: delete fom news where id in (select id from news s 
  where exists (select 1 from (
         select title, max(published) as published 
            from news 
            group by title having count(*) > 1) dn 
      where s.title = dn.title and s.published < dn.published));

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что ваше решение это выход. А данный код он безопасен в плане лишние ничего не хапнет когда будет 10к -50к строк  или как еще можно обезопасить?

Comment: как добавить в исключения поле `label` что бы по этому полю не было выборки. Что бы его как бы игнорировать. **А так вроде код подходит**